# Can I use docker compose mysql + spring boot container on kubernetes?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

Is it possible to use docker-compose MySQL + spring boot container on Kubernetes instead of creating two pods for MySQL and spring application? If so how?

Comment: on Kuberneter pod is the minimal unit that can exists. So no container or docker-compose directly on Kubernates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Its possible. You can create a tightly coupled pod with one container which contains MySQL and spring boot application in it, Or you can run two separate containers in single pod as [Sidecar](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/).

If you have docker-compose file, just convert it into kubernetes manifest file using [Kompose](https://kompose.io/)

Once your docker-compose file is converted into k8 yaml manifest. you can deploy it easily.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rezwan, it was really helpful, went with Kompose.